# Padding in NSTextView -- possible without custom drawing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

In Cocoa, `NSTextView` has a rather shallow margin between text and border. Is there a way to specify a padding (distance between text and border of view) for a `NSTextView` without resorting to owner drawing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The NSTextView method `setTextContainerInset:` does what you're looking for.  The **height** and **width** components of the `NSSize` parameter specify the **vertical** and **horizontal** padding amount respectively.

For example

```
textView.textContainerInset = NSSize(width: 8, height: 8)
```

Comment: Funny how I revisit this simple answer at least once a year